# How to enable Intellisense in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

Currently i am not getting any intellisense in the New Query, How to enable intellisense in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Standard Edition. Intellisense is working fine with DBs on new server, any option to have intellisense for DBs in server with SQL Server 2008

Comment: So, you are using SSMS 2014, but is the database in a server with SQL Server 2008+?

Comment: Yes, thats right. I created sample AdventureWorks DB and in that I am able to see intellisense. Any option to have intellisense for DBs in server with SQL Server 2008.

Comment: A third party application like sql prompt or similar, I don't really know them

Answer (score 3):

You can use dbforge SQL Complete, its a free(Express Edition) or paid(Standard  Edition) third party tool and you can download it from below link.

https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/download.html

I am using free(Express Edition) and it works fine for me.

Close SSMS, Install dbforge SQL Complete and reopen SSMS, hope it work for you.

Comment: I also downloaded dbforge and it works for me, Thanks for the solution.